# sizeWithAttributes gives the wrong height with NSFont on a mac when the point size is very small

Tags: macos, nsstring, appkit, nsfont

I am working on a mac app that lets the user zoom pretty far in on the content.  I need to measure the size of text that I render.  When I scale the font for the zoom the point size of the font is very small (i.e. 0.001).  When I use `[NSString sizeWithAttributes:]` to get the size of a string I get the correct width and I always get 1.0 for the height.  I also have an iOS app and this rendering class is used on both iOS and Mac.  On iOS when I use a `UIFont` with a point size of .001 I get the correct height when I call `sizeWithAttributes`.

Comment: At what point are you calling that in the view lifecycle, and are you using auto-layout?

Comment: This is in a layer.  I call it in `- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx` which is the layer equivalent of the `drawRect:` on an `NSView`.  I do use auto-layout to position the NSView that contain these layers.

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? Can you repro this in a smaller, isolated app (that you could share)? I suspect this is a bug in AppKit. Can you work around by  maybe caching the initial width/height ratio & divining the height on your own?

Comment: I am currently working around the issue with a bad hack :(  I calculate the font point size to pixel ratio for font size 10 and I then multiply that by the really small point size.  The size works correctly for everything I have tried so far.

Comment: Yeah, boo. That's too bad.

Comment: I haven't created a small stand alone sample project yet that I can post or submit to Apple for a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the same problem. The following sample code

```
#if TARGET_OS_IOS == 0
#define UIFont NSFont
#define NSStringFromCGSize NSStringFromSize
#endif

UIFont *uiFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:19];
CGSize boxSize = [@"1" sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:uiFont}];
NSLog(@"boxSize %@", NSStringFromCGSize(boxSize));
```

yields on iOS `boxSize {11.40185546875, 19}`, 
on macOS `boxSize {11.40185546875, 24}`.

My workaround:
Use CTFont.

```
CTFontRef _contentFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)@"Courier", 19, NULL);
CGGlyph glyphs[1];
UniChar chars[1];
chars[0] = '1';
bool rc = CTFontGetGlyphsForCharacters(_contentFont, chars, glyphs, 1);
if (rc) {
  double advance = CTFontGetAdvancesForGlyphs(_contentFont, kCTFontOrientationDefault, glyphs, NULL, 1);
  boxSize.width = advance;
  boxSize.height = CTFontGetAscent(_contentFont) + CTFontGetDescent(_contentFont);    
}
```